# Fast way to view the project file/folder on Remote Host in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, remote-host

Is there a way to select a file/folder in Project explorer and view the same file on Remote Host, if it exists of course.

Now you need to navigate from the root up to the desired file/folder, that can take some time...

[image: PhpStorm Remote Host]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navigate | Select in... | Remote Host` (<kbd>Alt + F1, 3</kbd> using Default keymap).

Works on whatever is focused -- current file in Editor; currently selected file in Project View panel etc.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, for solving yet another of my 'PhpStorm' questions!